# What wordpress bar is doing on Stack Exchange Blogs?

Tags: discussion, bug, blog-overflow

I was on a Stack Exchange site. I haven't gone to blog of any Stack Exchange site but today I went and something bothered my their.
I logged in to Stack Exchange site's blog and than **WordPress** bar came upon Stack Exchange bar.
[image]

**What is this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All [Stack Exchange blogs](https://stackexchange.com/blogs/) are Wordpress sites. You found one of those.

When you want to comment you can log in with your Stack Exchange site, at which point you'll see the header.

Judging by the header you are logged in to the [Islam SE blog](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/).

Comment: @martijnpieters I usually get this bar on my own word press sites. Can't Stack Exchange remove it?

Comment: @Murtaza: why would it need removing? The dashboard has useful functionality.

Comment: They design their own instead of WordPress.

Comment: That's a lot of work; what problem would that solve?

Comment: Not a problem but I feel like admin there.

Comment: @Murtaza: the bar is visible on any Wordpress site where you are logged in; you have an account there now, after all. Just because you encountered this only where your account has access rights makes that any less valid.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange blogs are currently powered by Wordpress - hence the toolbar.

Comment: Oh... that's on the **blog**; I didn't notice that. Oop!